# How does one create a function to call itself when a given condition is true in Mithril.js

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

This is my mithril code:

```js
m('input', {
    id: 'someBox',
    placeholder: 'Type something',
    oninput: () => {
        query = document.getElementById('someBox).value;
        //do something

        for(var a=0; a<500; ++a) {
            if(query != document.getElementById('someBox'))
                //call this function

            //do a lot of something
        }
    }
})
```

Whenever someone inputs a text, a set or results are supposed to load. When the input changes, the results that are supposed to be loaded doesn't change unless the previous results finish loading. So to prevent this from happening I decided to have a condition inside the `for()` loop. Currently I am using a `break;` statement, but for some reason it doesn't load the results sometimes.

Is there any way to name this function?

> **Note:** I cannot declare a function globally due to certain restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's not critical for you to use regular function (as opposed to arrow notation) attached to `oninput` property, you may refer to that function as `this.oninput`, like that:

```
m('input', {
    ...
    oninput: function(){
                ...
                if(query != document.getElementById('someBox'))
                //call this function
                this.oninput()
                ...
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: it worked. But I'm facing just one problem. I previously accessed an element from the outer class `this.props.textArea...`, but now that doesn't work because I know longer use the arrow function. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I fixed it thanks a lot for your help! I just made a variable `var textarea = this.props.textArea;` and passed `textarea` as an argument to a global function. This was actually what prevented me from using a global function in the first place.